# In-app purchase receipt validation, "in_app" field empty

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to validate in-app purchases using the post iOS 5 method of sending it to my server and having it validated there. The code in my app is pretty simple:

```
let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL!
let receipt = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)

// Get the receipt data from the app bundle
if let receipt = receipt {
    let requestContents: [String: NSString] = [
        "receipt_data" : receipt.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions([]))
    ]
    // send the receipt using NSURLSessionDataTask
}
```

The server side simply forwards the data to Apple and then parses it, and sends it back to the app. The problem is that the `in_app` field is unpredictably empty for a large number of customers (as seen through logging), but I can't reproduce this issue on any test devices or with beta testers.

What could cause this field to be an empty set? Per Apple's recommendation I've used `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` when this occurs, but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: I'm having this problem too, both in sandbox and production.

Comment: Prior to the last couple of days I've had no problem with the and the "in_app" array has always been populated with all the purchases made with that apple id. Maybe this is related to the recent app store outages?

Comment: @RowanJones just got finished talking to Apple. This is a known behavior change in their system that needs to be reported as a bug. Internally it is still debated as to whether they will revert the functionality to how it normally behaves or stick with the new behavior. If you haven't filed it already, please file a bug bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Is there an easy way on the client to already check whether in_app is empty so we could call `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` if necessary?

Comment: @hashier under the new functionality, `in_app` will always be empty after you call `SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(yourTransaction)`.

Comment: @InkGolem That I know but I won't call finishTransaction before I verified the receipt and I have the problem that our BE tells me sometimes that the `in_app` field is empty. So I want to check on the client first whether this field is empty or if I have to `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` first. So the question remains; how to I check if `in_app` is populated? (So I won't send empty receipts to the BE for verification)

Comment: @hashier You could make the request to Apple yourself, check the fields, and then send it to your validator. You just have to remember that you should always account for an empty field on your server because any communication between your app and Apple's server could be spoofed by malicious users.

Comment: @InkGolem yes, but I asked for locally verify it, not sending int to apple (: I guess there is no easy way. Probably the only way is pray open the PKCS #7 and read the double encoded ASN.1. Thanks

Comment: @InkGolem, i'm having a similar issue with in_app being empty for 20% of customers, did you find a suitable solution?

Comment: @tommychheng the last I heard it is an intentional change made by Apple. See my earlier comment.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2413/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40016228-CH1-RECEIPT-MY_APP_VALIDATES_ITS_RECEIPT_WITH_THE_APP_STORE_VIA_PAYMENTQUEUE_UPDATEDTRANSACTIONS__AFTER_A_SUCCESSFUL_PURCHASE__HOWEVER__THE_RETURNED_RECEIPT_CONTAINS_AN_EMPTY_IN_APP_ARRAY_RATHER_THAN_THE_EXPECTED_PRODUCTS_) this is expected behavior in certain cases, but unfortunately it is not documented what reasons might lead to such behavior. I would suspect that this can happen when validation of the user's credit card takes too long or some other temporary payment issue delays processing of the transaction, so reproducing this isn't feasible in the real-world. You should instead use unit tests and mock data to ensure your logic works properly.

A possible work-around is to [refresh the receipt](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skreceiptrefreshrequest) a couple of times with a few second delay in between requests. Ultimately if this fails you must inform the user that validation failed and provide an option to try again.